# PHP - Session half being logged in on tab close and re-open

Tags: php, session

On my website, I have a Nav bar which changes according to whether a user has logged in or not (If %_SESSION["username"] exists, a logout button is added.) This is fine and appears when the user logs in (when the user logs in, they are re-directed to the index page which then has the logout button.) If I then open up another tab, I get just home and login. When I press the login button, the logout button suddenly appears. How do I get it so the logout button appears, as if the user logs in, when opening another tab, or when closing/opening a tab.

I have done a test by echoing the $_SESSION["username"]. This echos fine when logged in, when opening a new tab, this errors as this variable doesn't exist. Once I press the login button, the user is then immediately logged in and it then echos the username.

This doesn't happen when the browser is fully closed as the session has been destroyed, but this bug is annoying when opening multiple tabs for this website, and doesn't show the user being logged in, when they are.

How Do I fix this?

CODE:

Index:

```
    session_start();
include("dbseinfo.php"); //Has info for connection to dbse
    echo '<div id="hmenu">';
    echo '<ul>'; 
    echo '<li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>';

if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){

echo '<li><a href="http://www.reddax.co.uk/logout.php">Logout</a></li>';

    $username=$_SESSION["username"];
```

Login

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header( "Location: index.php" );
}

(FORMS TO SEND OFF TO LOGIN_PROCESS.PHP)
```

Login_process

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header( "Location: index.php" );
}
include("dbse.inc.php");

$username=$_POST["username"];
$password=$_POST["password"];

   (Query to call username from databse)

if($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
if(password & username is correct)
{
    $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
    header('Refresh: 2; URL=index.php');
```

Comment: You should provide some code, ideally a condensed example where this behaviour can be reproduced. Does this happen with different browsers?

Comment: A little difficult as i've got the login system tied in to my database. It does occur in different browsers - Chrome, firefox, edge.

Comment: Well, from the top of my head I'd say that you're not assigning the same session to the user. Have you ensured that you have the same session ID on different tabs?

Comment: Added the code. I have lots of include files with private data so i've tried to put together the core code. Hopefully this helps?

Comment: Where is the `echo` that gives the error? Did you forget to call `session_start()` on that page?

Comment: Have you checked that your user gets the same session id on different tabs (look at the cookie value with the browsers dev tools)?

Comment: The echo statement i put in was in the index page just above the first if statement. This errors saying there is no value when creating a new tab. - I have no idea how to use the browser dev tools